# hide/show divs on link clicks not working on custom wordpress template file

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide/show div on link click. But it's not working properly on my site. I'm using this code on a custom WordPress template.

Following is my HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        
            <a id="link-edit-form" href="#" >PROFILE INFO</a><br/>
            <a id="link-reset-form" href="#">PASSWORD RESET</a><br/>
            <a id="link-logout-form" href="#">LOG OUT</a>
         
    </div>

<div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="paragraph-styles">
            <div id="edit-form-settings">
                <?php echo do_shortcode( '[wppb-edit-profile form_name="edit-profile"] ');?>
            </div>
            <div id="reset-form-settings">
                <?php echo do_shortcode( '[wppb-edit-profile form_name="password-reset"] ');?>
            </div>
            <div id="logout-form-settings">
                <?php echo do_shortcode( '[logout-btn] ');?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And following is my JS

```
<script>
    
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#link-edit-form').click(function() {
            jQuery('#reset-form-settings').hide();
            jQuery('#logout-form-settings').hide();
            jQuery('#edit-form-settings').show();
                        return false;
                    });        
                });

    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#link-reset-form').click(function() {
            jQuery('#edit-form-settings').hide();
            jQuery('#logout-form-settings').hide();
            jQuery('#reset-form-settings').show();
                        return false;
                    });        
                });     
    
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#link-logout-form').click(function() {
            jQuery('#edit-form-settings').hide();
            jQuery('#reset-form-settings').hide();
            jQuery('#logout-form-settings').show();
                        return false;
                    });        
                });                       

</script>
```

My console showing me 0 errors and struggling to find where the issue is

Comment: Minor improvement of your code: wrap all click functions in one "jQuery(function() { })", it will not fix the problem offcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to prevent the default event?

for every click function:

```
jQuery('#link-edit-form').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: @OldCeylonMudliar i tried running your code on codepen, and it seems to work... even without preventDefault(): https://codepen.io/gert-bruynseels/pen/OJRrPEq

Comment: @OldCeylonMudliar Wordpress does not effect the client side js code. I think it is not loaded on your page. But the jQuery code above works.